viewDidLoad is not called though it is the root view controller
Hi I am fairly new to swift, the problem is that the viewDidLoad is never called. what am I missing?
the following are the entry point swift code and the ViewContoller code, they are under the same project.
// PolaroidEffectAppApp.swift
import UIKit

@main

class PolaroidEffectAppApp: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        // Create a window that fills the screen
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        
        // Check if the window is properly initialized
               guard let window = window else {
                   print("Error: Window could not be initialized.")
                   return false
               }
    
        // Create the root view controller
      **  let rootViewController = ViewController()**
    
        // Create a navigation controller with the root view controller
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    
        // Set the window's root view controller to the navigation controller
        window.rootViewController = navigationController
        print("the app will have active view controller.") //printed out successfully in testing
    
        // Make the window visible
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
        return true
    }

}

//  ViewController.swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    let photoEditorView = PhotoEditorView() // Initialize the PhotoEditorView
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("View loaded")//did not print in testing
        setupUI()
    }
    
    func setupUI() {
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        // Add the PhotoEditorView to the view hierarchy
        view.addSubview(photoEditorView)
        
        // Set constraints or frame for PhotoEditorView
        photoEditorView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            photoEditorView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            photoEditorView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            photoEditorView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            photoEditorView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    
        // Add navigation button to select photo
        let selectPhotoButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Select Photo", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(selectPhoto))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = selectPhotoButton
        
        // Connect actions
        photoEditorView.applyButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(applyEffect), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func selectPhoto() {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func applyEffect() {
        guard let image = photoEditorView.imageView.image else { return }
        let grainIntensity = photoEditorView.grainSlider.value
        let scratchIntensity = photoEditorView.scratchSlider.value
        
        let filteredImage = GrainAndScratchFilter.apply(to: image, grainIntensity: grainIntensity, scratchIntensity: scratchIntensity)
        photoEditorView.imageView.image = filteredImage
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let pickedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            photoEditorView.imageView.image = pickedImage
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

I have some break points set up in the @main sections they are all hit, but after it hit "return true" of the func application, it stopped there, it did not hit any of the breakpoints in ViewController

Does your app have a scene delegate? If yes, you should move your window and root view controller initialization to the scene delegate's scene(_:willConnectTo:options:) method.

Thanks! you are right, it should have a SceneDelegate by default, but it didn't, because when I created the project it used SwiftUI. What I should have done is  switching it to storyboard, then manually remove the storyboard and references from the project, and go from there, now the UI works.

There is no viewDidLoad in SwiftUI.

The problem is resolved by creating the project switching from using SwiftUI to storyboard. Then manually remove the storyboard references.
